# Bootstrap-Material-Design 4 Dropdown not opening in Jhipster(Angular 5)

Tags: bootstrap-4, jhipster, angular5, bootstrap-material-design

I am trying to use a creative-tim Material Bootstrap 4 Theme in my jHipster project, but after so many tries I am not able to make the Dropdown or Floating Label components working.

Stuff I tried:
1. Added files in vendor.ts

```
import "../../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js";
import "../../../../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js";
import '../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';
import "../../../../node_modules/arrive/src/arrive.js";
import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/js/ripples.js";
import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.js";
```

2. Added css/scss in vendor.scss

   @import 'node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design';
   @import '../../../../../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
3. Added @import 'material-dashboard.scss'; in global.scss
4. These are the dependencies of package.json

   "dependencies": {
   "@angular/animations": "^5.2.4",
   "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.1",
   "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
   "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
   "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
   "@angular/http": "5.2.0",
   "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
   "@angular/material": "^5.2.1",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
   "@angular/router": "5.2.0",
   "arrive": "2.3.1",
   "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.9",
   "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
   "bootstrap-material-design": "^4.1.1",
   "core-js": "2.4.1",
   "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
   "generator-jhipster-entity-audit": "^3.1.0",
   "jquery": "3.2.1",
   "ng-jhipster": "0.4.0",
   "ngx-cookie": "2.0.1",
   "ngx-infinite-scroll": "0.5.1",
   "ngx-webstorage": "2.0.1",
   "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
   "rxjs": "5.5.6",
   "swagger-ui": "2.2.10",
   "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
   "sweetalert2": "6.10.1",
   "tether": "1.4.0",
   "zone.js": "0.8.19",
   "ng-diff-match-patch": "2.0.6"
   }

But still the Dropdown and Floating Labels are not working. Please help me integrate http://md-pro-angular.creative-tim.com/dashboard?_ga=2.247609543.1315334517.1519214351-1513144354.1517469381 theme in my hipster app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything is opening there for me.

Comment: @WebDevBooster Can you please share your code. Did you tried with jhipster?

Comment: My code? I clicked the link. You need to clear your browser cache. That's it.

Comment: @WebDevBooster No that's the working theme which I have purchased I need to integrate in a jHipster project.

Comment: Then you need to start by reading this page here: [mcve]

Comment: If you purchased it, have you contacted their support?